# How to mark all the checkboxes with Selenium Webdriver using Java?

Tags: automated-testing, java, selenium-webdriver

I want to mark all the checkboxes in a page using selenium webdriver?

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

First, assign all checkbox elements to a list.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//input[type='checkbox']"));
```

Then, loop through the list, for example

```
for(WebElement el : list){
    if(!el.isChecked()) // validate Checked property, otherwise you'll uncheck!
        el.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List <webelement> checkboxele= driver.findelements(By..whatever property you wish, id or xpath")
for(webelement ele:checkboxele){

ele.click();
//Thread.sleep(1000); depends
}
```

This will click on all checkboxes in your page.

Comment: Why would you sleep for checking checkboxes?

Comment: if there are multiple checkboxes, sync issue can happen right?

Comment: For a simple case like this, Selenium has in my experience never failed without sleeping.

Comment: hmm..okay. I just added it for extra safety. Maybe, I dont have enough experience like you.

Comment: adding sleep for "extra safety" without understanding why or what it does is  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming